Generalized Hamming weights for binary BCH codes
Cross posting from MSE. I think it might be a good fit here.
Given a linear binary code $C$, the $r$-th generalized Hamming weight $d_{r}(C)$ is the minimal support size of an $r$-dimensional subcode of $C$ (so $d_{1}(C)$ is simply the code's distance).
For a code length $n = 2^{m}-1$, and a designated distance $d=2t+1$, let's denote $\text{BCH}(n,d)$ the binary BCH code of distance $d$ (that corrects $t$ errors). It is known that the co-dimension of $\text{BCH}(n,d)$ is $tm$.
For concreteness, say we are interested in the constant $t$ case (say even $t=3$). What is known about the generalized Hamming weights $d_{r}(\text{BCH}(n,d))$ for all ranges of $r$? I found this paper, which seems to only give the answer when $r$ is either constant, or when $r$ is constantly-close to $k$, the code's dimension.
Specifically, what is known when, say, $r = 0.1m$? Any meaningful bound would be good, I'm not necessarily looking for the exact answer.
I chose BCH just as a concrete example, but any linear, binary, code with "BCH-like" parameters is just as good (namely, constant distance with $O(\log n)$ co-dimension).
